# How to transpose individual characters using sed

Tags: sed, posix

I'm trying to transpose the 3rd digit with the 8th digit. Trying this with the phone number:

```
(888) 747-7424
```

After transposition:

```
(884) 747-7824
```

This is what I have:

```
sed -E 's/(..)(.)(....)(.)(.*)/\1\4\3\2\5/'
```

It transposes the 2nd and the 5th digit.

Answer (score 1):

You just miscounted characters:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.{3})(.)(.{7})(.)/\1\4\3\2/' file
(884) 747-7824
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only swap the *digits*, you need to match digits after any 0 or more non-digit chars:

```
sed -E 's/^(([^0-9]*[0-9]){2}[^0-9]*)([0-9])(([^0-9]*[0-9]){4}[^0-9]*)([0-9])/\1\6\4\3/'
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/vWFNEf):

```
s='(888) 747-7424'
sed -E 's/^(([^0-9]*[0-9]){2}[^0-9]*)([0-9])(([^0-9]*[0-9]){4}[^0-9]*)([0-9])/\1\6\4\3/' <<< "$s"
# => (884) 747-7824
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(([^0-9]*[0-9]){2}[^0-9]*)` - Group 1: two occurrences of non-digits followed with a digit, then 0 or more non-digits
- `([0-9])` - Group 3: a digit
- `(([^0-9]*[0-9]){4}[^0-9]*)` - Group 4: four occurrences of non-digits followed with a digit, then 0 or more non-digits
- `([0-9])` - Group 6: a digit.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]/\n&/3;s//\n&/8;s/\n(.)(.*)\n(.)/\3\2\1/' file
```

This delimits each required digit by a newline then uses pattern matching to swap the two digits.

To make this atomic, use:

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]/\n&/8;T;s//\n&/3;s/\n(.)(.*)\n(.)/\3\2\1/' file
```